# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function xdebug_disable()

Tags: magento2, xdebug

I am working with the Magento 2.3, and using the PHPStorm as a IDE. Recently I've configured the xdebug in my local for identify some process flow. But it does not helped me to checked the flow.

Then I hit the website in local, I am facing
**the Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function xdebug_disable() in vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/_bootstrap.php on line 73**

I've checked with google bug I couldn't find any proper solution for this.
Right now I am using the nginx with PHP7.2

I am looking forward to your support to fix the problem.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/_bootstrap.php

**From :-**

```
if (!(bool)$debugMode && extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
    xdebug_disable();
}
```

**To :-**

```
if (!(bool)$debugMode && extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
    if (function_exists('xdebug_disable')) {
        xdebug_disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a quick workaround that worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

You're using Xdebug 3, Magento 2.3 only supports Xdebug 2. You need to downgrade your locally installed Xdebug to the latest version in the 2.x release - `pecl install -f xdebug-2.9.8` should work I believe, assuming you have pecl installed.

Comment: Is that right version?

Comment: it was still not working after downgrade xdebug

Comment: I tried the above mentioned command in my system, but it's not install the xdebug, do you any other command to install the particular xdebug version

Comment: Its also not installing xdebug for me as well, any one had fixed it ?

Comment: why is it not installing xdebug? what error are you getting?

Answer (score 6):

This is a **bug** in `magento2-functional-testing-framework` which conflict with xdebug 3, bacause `xdebug_disable()` was removed in Xdebug 3.

The bug was fixed in the `magento2-functional-testing-framework` version 3.2.1.

---

Before the new version is merged in Magento, we could use the quick workaround which from the commit [MQE-2391: [GitHub Issue] Magento fails with xdebug 3 due to mftf](https://github.com/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/commit/e95fb10d3a55d72af5d60e07703d09201812599e) in version 3.2.1:

In the file `dev/tests/functional/standalone_bootstrap.php` remove the codes below

```
if (!(bool)$debug_mode && extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
    xdebug_disable();
}
```

In the file `src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/_bootstrap.php` remove the codes below

```
if (!(bool)$debugMode && extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
    xdebug_disable();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue after updating and upgrading my Ubuntu server. I needed to downgrade xDebug version to  fix this issue for Magento 2.4.1 and PHP7.4:

> sudo pecl install -f xdebug-2.9.8

If you get “phpize: command not found” error, you can run pecl command again:

> sudo apt-get install php7.4-dev

I use multiple PHP versions on my server. For older version like PHP7.3, you modified its php.ini file and add the path of xdebug-2.9.8. On ubuntu, I edited php.ini by running:

```
sudo vi /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

and added:

`zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so`

Answer (score 0):

To add on to `smstl`'s answer, which is correct, the problematic files comes from `\Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework`, which you can remove if not used by running: `composer remove --dev magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework`