# Magento 2: How to install & configure xdebug (linux +magento+ sublime)

Tags: magento2, xdebug

Is their any way to configure xdebug on linux+magento+sublime debug environment ?

I am using `PHP Version 7.3.26-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 2):

﻿**Configure Xdebug for Magento 2**

1. I assumed you have already installed below softwares

   - Ubuntu 18.04
   - PHP 7.4
   - Apache/2.4.29
   - Sublime Text 4 (Build 4113)
   - Magento 2.4.x
2. Xdebug Installation

   - Install xdebug on ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Please use below command

   sudo apt-get install php-xdebug

   - We need to install a php specific version as well.

   sudo apt-get install php7.4-xdebug
3. Locate xdebug.ini file

   - First we need to find the xdebug.ini file for both command line php and apache fpm php.
   - First we will find out xdebug.ini for apache fpm.
   - Create a new php page add phpinfo() function add open url using browser.
     We will get the xdebug.ini file path.
     [image]
   - Apache fpm xdebug.ini file path is

   /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

   - Execute below command it will give xdebug.ini file path for command line php.

   php --ini

   [image]

   - Command line php xdebug.ini file path is

   /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
4. PHP configuration for xdebug

   - We need to configure php to use xdebug.
   - We need to configure both the php installations command line and apache fpm php.
   - Add below line of code in both (cli and fpm) xdebug.ini file, If this code already does not exist.

   zend_extension=xdebug

   [image]
   [image]

   - Restart the apache 2 server using command below

   sudo service apache2 restart
5. Verify xdebug installation

   - On command line we can verify xdebug installation using command line

     php -v
   - On apache2 web server create a php page and below code.

   echo  xdebug_info();
6. Xdebug configuration

   - We need to configure both the php installations command line and apache fpm php.
   - Open  xdebug.ini file using below commands

   sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
   sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

   - Add below code in both xdebug.ini files
     zend_extension=xdebug.so
     xdebug.client_port=9000

   xdebug.mode=debug

   xdebug.start_with_request=yes

   xdebug.idekey=sublime.xdebug

   xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1

   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

   xdebug.remote_port=9000

   - Restart the apache 2 server
     sudo apache2 service restart
7. Sublime Text 4 Configuration

   - Please make sure you have already installed Package Control.
     If you not installed package control, Please install this using below link
     https://packagecontrol.io/installation
   - Start sublime text editor. Go to “Tools > Command > Palette” search for the install package.
     [image]
   - Now search for the “Xdebug Client”  package and install this package.
     https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Xdebug%20Client
     https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug
   - Open sublime project file (projectName.sublime-project) and add below code.

   "settings": {
   "xdebug": {
   "url": "http://m2p/index.php",
   "super_globals": true,
   "close_on_stop": true
   }
   }

   Here http://m2p/index.php is our magento website link.

   [image]
8. Start/Stop the Xdebug session

   - Now we will start the xdebug session. Go to “Tools > Xdebug > Start Debugging (Launch Browser)”
   - This will start the xdebug session.
     This will also open your website home page with “?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug” added in the url.

   [image]

   - Add Breakpoints

     - Open the php file which you want to debug
     - Right click on the line where you want to add a breakpoint. Go to the Xdebug menu and click on the Add/Remove breakpoint option.

     [image]
   - Load the url http://m2p/test.php using the browser. You will see the code debugger started.
     [image]
9. Troubleshooting

   - After installation of xdebug if you reload the site home page and you get 500 errors. I got this error while configuring xdebug on     Magento2.3. If you got this error please use the below solution.
   - First check your apache error log file. If your error log file contains errors like below.
     PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function xdebug_disable()
   - Please refer to the solution below to resolve this error.
     [Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function xdebug_disable()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327971/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-xdebug-disable)
10. Happy debugging
11. Thank You